# MS Dynamics CRM : how to delete child record when parent record is deleted using plugin in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

MS Dynamics CRM : how to delete child record of 2 child entities on dependent primary name field when parent record is deleted using plugin in MS CRM

Comment: What have you already tried

Comment: Can you set up the relationship so that Child records are deleted or is there some other constraint preventing this?

Comment: Cascading Delete: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309412.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Cascading delete.

If you want to handle it in your code, though:

1) fetch the children of those records
2) delete the children using org service
3) delete the parent using org service

Comment: Which parts are you looking for?